# STM32f4 USB cdc communication how to achive more than 500 kbps speed

Tags: usb, stm32, freertos, stm32f4

We are using stm32f446ze mcu with 24 Mhz crystal and freertos in project.
currenty USB cdc communication is getting about 500 kbps and want achieve more than this.
ST documents says that max speed is about 1Mbps. Is there any reference or source or example programs.

*) How to implement double buffering in USB cdc communication
*) Which usb library is best for speed 
*) Is there any open source USB library that can achive this speed
Thank you

Comment: any, but you need to understand how the USB works to send correct data sized buffers and  send procedure. USB is by as easy as UART. other side (host) has to be ready to receive this stream of data as well (device only sends on seruest)

Comment: If you are using ST USB stack you'll never get that speed if you don't tweak it heavily as it manages every transaction by software and trigger a lot of interrupts for each transfer.
As that was my way of dealing with I would suggest you to avoid it. Better if you write it down from scratch or choose another stack.

Comment: thanks for replay Is there any free USB stack (Please name them) for stm controllers that we can try

Comment: @Damiano it is possible and I use stm32f3 with HAL and over 1MBps speed.

Comment: @P__J__ in device mode or host mode? I'm talking about the host mode.

Comment: @Damiano - so your comment is not related to the question.

Comment: @P__J__ I don't think that was specified maybe jaggu77 could specify it

Comment: STM32f4 is used as device mode